# Getting wrong spatial result in SQL server + management studio (2014) when parse from MultiPolygon WKT

Tags: c#, sql-server, geojson, geography, wkt

SQL query for parsing WKT to DbGeography:

```
select geography::STMPolyFromText('MULTIPOLYGON (((-2.5591667 49.2208332, -2.4799491 49.2644641, -2.3891134 49.2959748, -2.2950459 49.325767, -2.2176605 49.3624676, -2.1335686 49.4074579, -2.0975001 49.4605, -1.9925 49.3646667, -1.8916667 49.3166667, -1.8333334 49.2508333, -1.8333333 49.1833333, -1.8591667 49.0658333, -1.9428333 48.9646666, -1.9833333 48.9416666, -1.9833333 48.9365843, -1.9833333 48.8833333, -2.0833333 48.8721666, -2.2416668 48.8721666, -2.5253334 48.9278333, -2.5253333 49.0595, -2.5591667 49.2208332)))',4326)
```

Its display spatial result as below image
[image]

When i convert this WKT to GeoJson Using [GeoJSON4EntityFramework](https://github.com/alatas/GeoJSON4EntityFramework), and load this geojson in google map by below code:

```
map.data.addGeoJson(geoJsonObject);
```

its draws below map
[image]

Please help me find-out which is correct from both above images.

If SQL partial result of SQL Management Studio is wrong, then how can i correct this?

Comment: You need to reverse the order of the points in your polygon. When you draw a polygon on a sphere, there's no natural "inside" or "outside" - consider drawing a line around the equator - are we enclosing the northern hemisphere or the southern one? Since SQL Server allows polygons that encompass more than half of the planet, it uses a different rule to determine inside and outside. (the "left-hand" rule)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever is correct. Alternatively, in even moderately modern versions of SQL Server, you can call the `ReorientObject()` method on your geography instance and it will reverse the points for you. Neat!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have findout the answer. We can know SqlGeography is larger than a hemisphere or not by "m_isLargerThanAHemisphere" Boolean value from non-public property value.

below code for to get "m_isLargerThanAHemisphere" value:

```
                SqlGeography sqlGeography = SqlGeography.Parse(geoWKT);

                object geoData = PropertyHelper.GetPrivatePropertyValue<object>(sqlGeography, "GeoData");
                bool m_isLargerThanAHemisphere = PropertyHelper.GetPrivateFieldValue<bool>(geoData, "m_isLargerThanAHemisphere");
                if (m_isLargerThanAHemisphere)
                {
                    sqlGeography = sqlGeography.ReorientObject();
                }
                bool isValid = sqlGeography.STIsValid().Value;
                if (!isValid)
                {
                    sqlGeography = sqlGeography.MakeValid();
                    isValid = sqlGeography.STIsValid().Value;
                }
                DbGeography dbGeography = DbGeography.FromText(sqlGeography.ToString(), 4326);
```

[PropertyHelper class reference](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/Common/PropertyHelper.cs)